# Linux tool to send raw data to a TCP server

Tags: linux, tcp

I am aware that this is not a direct 'development' question but I need this info to test a development project, so I think someone could've hit similar problem.

I will test a software that runs a TCP server and according to sent commands replies some answers. I will test the software and do not want to write code if it doesn't work well. So I want to send those commands and test drive the server software.

How can I achieve this with a Linux box?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[netcat](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/58) or [telnet](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?telnet), i have used both in the past to test simple text based protocols. netcat is more flexible.

Comment: @YannRamin how do I use socat to send a TCP message? I previously could send a UDP message with socat but socat doesn't have `tcp-datagram`. This is for UDP: `echo "some-test-sample" | socat - UDP-DATAGRAM:localhost:43278,broadcast`

Answer (score 69):

From bash with dd:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=9000 count=1000 > /dev/tcp/$target_host/$port
```

or even with cat:

```
cat < /dev/urandom > /dev/tcp/$target_host/$port
```

Comment: `/dev/tcp/*/*` is a special filename that bash handles in a special way. It doesn't actually exist.

Comment: `(echo '2' > /dev/tcp/192.168.1.161/8888) && (sleep 1; echo '2' > /dev/tcp/192.168.1.163/8888)` why more then 1 takes 5 minutes but when used 1 request then less then 1 second its done?

Comment: While `nc` is possibly the best tool, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Just a sidenote: With this, the response from the server will not be displayed. If you want to see the response on the screen, netcat fits better.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [Expect](http://expect.nist.gov/) may be what you want. There are implementations for multiple scripting languages, and you can script *and assert* the requests/server responses plus appropriate timeouts, error handling etc.

Comment: Please show some example, its rare to find someone who understand the expect properly for multiple TCP connection. I have an issue when i do single connect it works but when it comes multi connection it takes more then normal duration. Please show some example how can you do this with expect? `(echo '2' > /dev/tcp/192.168.1.161/8888) && (sleep 1; echo '2' > /dev/tcp/192.168.1.163/8888)`

Comment: I'm surprised this gets downvoted, when the top voted and accepted answer recommends telnet to "test simple text based protocols"