# How to use curl/wget to send command and get response to a telnet server

Tags: curl, wget, telnet

I have a C Program running on the server that listens on a port#, takes a few commands, and for each, it sends a response. I could do:

telnet   and then enter the command, and get the response.
It is also possible to automate the telnet using expect script, etc.
But does curl/wget allow to do this without any scripting? E.g. usage:

```
$ telnet <ip> 25000 
Trying <ip>...
Connected to <ip>.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET ALL
```

(Result of the command now follows)

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux tool to send raw data to a TCP server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010507/linux-tool-to-send-raw-data-to-a-tcp-server)

Comment: Yes, this is the right way, thanks for pointing out. I can run socat as:  'echo "GET ALL" | socat tcp:<ip>:<port> stdio